# swift 3 variable used before begin initialized

Tags: swift

I have an issue with my `n` variable. I cannot use `n` in for loop. Why? `n` was initialized before for loop. Please, help.

```
import Foundation

var n: Int
var t: Int

while(true){

    var tt = readLine()
    t = Int(tt!)!
    if (t==0){
        break
    }
    else if ( t < 0){
        n = t*(-1)
    }
    else if(t > 0){
        n = t
    }
    var arr : [[String]] = []
    for i in 0..<n*2{
        for y in 0..<n*2{
            arr[i][y] = "."
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### A variable *may* be declared and not immediately initialized, as long as initialization is guaranteed before first use

The error is more subtle than at first glance. You may actually declare a property without initializing it, as long as all program flows leading to its first use ascertain initialization of it.

The issue is with the `if`, `else if` and `else if` block:

```
var n: Int // declaration

// ...

if (t == 0) {
    break
}
else if (t < 0) {
    n = t*(-1)
}
else if (t > 0){
    n = t
}

// first use
for i in 0..<n*2 { /* ... */ }
```

Swift cannot not infer that this block is in fact exhaustive, and believes that there is a possibility that none of the above `if` statements holds, which, in the eyes of the compiler, would lead to the following program state:

- program flow has not been broken (`break`)
- and `n` has not been instantiated

As humans, however, we know that the `if - else if - else if` block above is indeed exhaustive, and can help the compiler out by simply changing the last `if else` statement to a simple `else` statement.

```
if (t == 0) {
    break
}
else if (t < 0) {
    n = t*(-1)
}
// if none of the above, t > 0
else {
    n = t
}
```

---

On another note, the nested array access of non-existing array elements, `arr[i][y] = "."` will lead to a runtime exception, but this is another issue. In its current form, it looks as if the intent with the nested loops could be replaced with a nested array instantiation:

```
var arr = [[String]](repeating: [String](repeating: ".", count: 2*n), count: 2*n)
```

or,

```
var arr = (0..<2*n).map { _ in [String](repeating: ".", count: 2*n) }
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `n` is only declared, not initialized.

To initialize the variables:

```
var n: Int = 0
var t: Int = 0
```